# How to append a list as a row in pandas.DataFrame()?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, data-analysis

I am iteratively reading a log file and parsing/extracting data and would like to append that to a dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['item','price','qty','sold'])
with open("mylogfile") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        data = extract_data(line)
        df.append(data) ## ?


def extract_data(line):
   # parse and get values as a list
   return list_values
```

Update:
I get the following error:
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (0, 0), indices imply (4, 0)

Also, My log file has data in the format

```
item,2,price,4.5,qty,17,sold,11
item,12,price,14.5,qty,7,sold,4
item,2,price,4.5,qty,13,sold,2
```

Edit2: (the actual file is, and i am only interested in the 'item' line

```
item,2,price,4.5,qty,17,sold,11
a,12,b,14,c,18,d,15,e16
item,12,price,14.5,qty,7,sold,4
x,4,y,1,z,81
a,12,b,14,c,18,d,15,e16
a,14,b,11,c,8,d,51,e26
item,2,price,4.5,qty,13,sold,2
x,14,y,11,z,8
```

Comment: What's the problem? Does the code above not work?

Comment: Please post data that reproduces your error, basically you need to return either a Series or DataFrame to append to your existing df, also this is horribly inefficient, what is the format of your data? You can probably use any of the existing methods to read it in and create the df once: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a multi-step approach:

```
In [210]:
# read in as csv, set header to None
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None)
df

Out[210]:
      0   1      2     3    4   5     6   7
0  item   2  price   4.5  qty  17  sold  11
1  item  12  price  14.5  qty   7  sold   4
2  item   2  price   4.5  qty  13  sold   2

In [213]:
# extract the header names from the first row
col_names = df.iloc[0][0::2]
print(col_names)
# extract the data columns we will use later to filter the df
col_list = df.columns[1::2]
col_list
0     item
2    price
4      qty
6     sold
Name: 0, dtype: object

Out[213]:
Int64Index([1, 3, 5, 7], dtype='int64')

In [214]:
# now filter the df to the columns that actually have your data
df = df[col_list]
# assign the column names
df.columns = col_names
df

Out[214]:
0  item  price  qty  sold
0     2    4.5   17    11
1    12   14.5    7     4
2     2    4.5   13     2
```

So I would read it as a csv using `read_csv`, don't copy my code verbatim, substitute `io.StringIO(t)` with the path to your text file.

**UPDATE**

A better approach would be to read a single line in, extract the header names and cols of interest and then read the whole file in again but select just those columns of interest and pass the name of columns in:

```
In [217]:

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None, nrows=1)
df
Out[217]:
      0  1      2    3    4   5     6   7
0  item  2  price  4.5  qty  17  sold  11
In [218]:

col_names = df.iloc[0][0::2]
print(col_names)
col_list = df.columns[1::2]
col_list
0     item
2    price
4      qty
6     sold
Name: 0, dtype: object
Out[218]:
Int64Index([1, 3, 5, 7], dtype='int64')
In [219]:

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), usecols=col_list, names=col_names)
df
Out[219]:
   item  price  qty  sold
0     2    4.5   17    11
1    12   14.5    7     4
2     2    4.5   13     2
```

Comment: Thanks. My log file also has other type of lines in the csv that I am ignoring. I am reading it line by line and only extracting data from interesting line(s).

Comment: @amehta this is really poor to be honest, you've posted a question and asked for help and now you've posted a sample of the real data that is quite different from what you initially posted and has quite different characteristics

Comment: you can still load the data in and just filter out the rows that don't have the value 'item' in them so after loading just do `df[df.item != 'item']` you then need to process the filtered df again

Comment: I actually did not need help in reading/loading my actual data. I was doing my own filtering and needed assistance in appending the interesting data to a dataframe. Sicere, apologies, for changing the question dyanmic based on your answers and thanks for answering!